# Prediction for RBM in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rbm

I would like to use RBM in scikit. I can define and train a RBM like many other classifiers.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
clf = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I can't seem to find a function that makes me a prediction. I am looking for an equivalent for one of the following in scikit.

```
y_score = clf.decision_function(X_test)
y_score = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Neither functions are present in BernoulliRBM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BernoulliRBM is an unsupervised method so you won't be able to do `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)` but rather `clf.fit(X_train)`. It is mostly used for non-linear feature extraction that can be feed to a classifier. It would look like this:

```
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
rbm = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)

classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('logistic', logistic)])
```

So the features extracted by rbm are passed to the LogisticRegression model. Take a look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html) for a full example.

Comment: For RBM what type of vectorizer would match nicely in order to do unsupervised learning as a previous step for text classification?.

Comment: In theory a linear classifier, because the RBM should have extracted the non-linearities, but I don't think this this question can be answered in general. Is very data dependent.

Comment: Can I use this code to fill missing values? Does it require any modifications?